# How to filter a table based on a input [Symfony 3]

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

Currently I'm an intern working with PHP. I have this table where I get the sum of all the hours of all the projects:

It looks like this:

**Project || Hours**

Project1 || 20:30
Project2 || 15:00

I need to filter the hours in an user-submitted interval.

I thought about placing 2 inputs to filter but I don't know exactly *how* to do the filter.

I'm thinking about creating a new route to the page, am I on the right direction?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please review the [guide to asking good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).  Stack Overflow isn't a code writing service, and it's assumed that you'll have done at least some preliminary work before asking here.  What have you already tried?  What was not working about it?  Answer these questions with code examples, and you're more likely to get a good answer to a good question.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your question seems abit too open 
try creating an input that accept time(hrs) values that way you an sum for each.
the sample below can help

```
    $minute = date("i", $h2);
    $second = date("s", $h2);
    $hour = date("H", $h2);

    $convert = strtotime("+$minute minutes", $h);
    $convert = strtotime("+$second seconds", $convert);
    $convert = strtotime("+$hour hours", $convert);
    $Time = date('H:i:s', $convert); // this will helpin the sum of the hrs(time)
```